# Multiple dunn tests on subsets of data

Tags: r, iteration

I would like to run a total of 4 Dunn tests on my data, on four subsets of it, dummy data, where grp is the grouping I use for the dunn test:

```
          d      var1  var2 grp
-1.26431512      a      c   A
 1.28852253      b      d   A
-0.06951728      a      c   A
 0.21254560      b      c   Z
-0.20723889      b      d   Z
 0.02315806      b      d   Z
```

at the moment I'm filtering for each variable and then running dunn.test:

```
a_c<-filter(df, var1 %in% "a", var2 %in% "c")
a_c_results<-dunn.test(df$d, g=df$grp, method="bh")
```

and so on for the four combinations, `a_c, a_d, b_c, b_d`

I've tried this code, because it worked really well on the Kruskal-Wallis test I ran before,
however as the Dunn test output is a list, so I assume that's why this approach isn't working:

```
dunn_results<-df %>%
        group_by(var1, var2) %>%
        summarise(p.value=dunn.test(d, grp)$p.value)
```

I get the following error from the code above:

```
Error: column 'p.value' is of unsupportetd type NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

**Dunn test structure**

You're pretty close. The issue isn't that `dunn.test` returns a list -- you're handling that correctly. The issue is that the list doesn't have a member called `p.value.`

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(dunn.test)

rslt <- dunn.test(df$d, df$grp)
str(rslt)
#> List of 5
#>  $ chi2       : num 0.0476
#>  $ Z          : num -0.218
#>  $ P          : num 0.414
#>  $ P.adjusted : num 0.414
#>  $ comparisons: chr "A - Z"
rslt$p.value
#> NULL
```

This should work, though:

```
dunn_results <- df %>%
  group_by(var1, var2) %>%
  summarise(p.value = dunn.test(d, grp)$P)
```

---

**UPDATE: Additional error handling**

That's not quite the end, since `dunn.test()` can return errors. In the sample set, there are two errors:

1. "too few observations in x." for the b-c combination in row 4.
2. "argument is of length zero" for the a-c combination in rows 1, 3.

So we'll need to put our function that runs the Dunn test and extracts the vector of P-values inside an error-trapping function. This will silently return NA's for any error that a Dunn test experiences as the p.value for the summary.

```
dunn_test_wrapper <- function(x, y) {
  tryCatch(dunn.test(x, y)$P, error = function(cond) NA)
}

dunn_results<-df %>%
  group_by(var1, var2) %>%
  summarise(p.value = dunn_test_wrapper(d, grp))
```

Comment: Thank you! When I try both solutions, I get an error, the first solution, gives me this: ```Error: Column 'p.value' must be length 1 (a summary vlaue, not 105``` the second option, which I agree is better because the full test summary is more informative, and I got the same error.

Comment: @watermineporcupine You're absolutely right. I should have tested with your grouping. Dunn test can produce errors, so we need to trap them. Hopefully this also works on your full dataset as well. Updated the post accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! But I still seem to get the same error,is it possible that it is to do with the fact that `dunn.test` outputs a table of multiple comparisons (in the form of a list) as opposed to a vector of p-values?